# I am unable to submit the form due to the jquery-validation alert in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

`_layoutpage.cshtml`:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts")
```

`Login.cshtml`:

```
@section Scripts {
          @{
              <partial name="_PartialValidation"/>
          }
}
```

In partial validation [`_ParialValidation.cshtml`] I've included.

```
<script src="<path-to-jquery-validation> </script>
```

PS: validation is working.

I've used jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js for client side validation.

It validates the form data properly.

But the problem is:

1. It's only showing the alert box while submitting form (only front-end working)
2. Form is not navigating to the controller (c#)

What I want:

1. Back-end validation too.

If you've faced this too please help me. I'm new to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Please follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to have a quick start. I think it will help you.

Comment: Did you take a try follow the official document?

Answer (score -1):

Just remove @ { } around the _PartialValidation and try.

```js
@section Scripts{

<partial name="_PartialValidation"/>
             
}
```

Comment: nope! still not working